# How can I farm in World of Warcraft Wrath of the Lich King?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Can anyone tell me a good gold farming place in the World of Warcraft? A farming place list is what I need (please include levels too).

Comment: Farm what? XP? :-/

Comment: No, I would like to farm gold.

Comment: what level are you? Horde or Alliance?

Comment: I'm at level 41. My character is in the Alliance.

Comment: In my time playing WoW, a long time ago i was able to make at least 100 times more money at the auction house then anywhere else. I never understood the korean farming stuff back then, if i moved to that place i probably earned myself a good living from a couple hours of WoW AH each day.

Answer (score 2):

The most effective way of making money in World of Warcraft is generally to select a couple of harvesting professions, and do regular rounds for these, then sell the result on the auction house.

There are quite a few good resources you can find via Google, such as [this one](http://www.wow-professions.com/farming-guides) that show where you should look for different items.

What is worthwhile on your server is obviously dependent on its own market, but I'd suggest going for Mining and Herbalism as it's typically less time-consuming than Skinning to do these.